# How to cut some part x-axis

Tags: plotting

I would like add parallel line to $x$ axis to emphasize that part is longer than it appears. See the figure I added (highlited part).

[image]

**Additional request:** Is it possible get longer ticks?

Here is my MWE:

```
f1[i_] := 2883.03 + (27645.2 i^0.993489)/(0.248356 + i^0.993489)

ticks = {

   {Table[{10^(3 + i), Superscript[10, 3 + i]}, {i, 0.4, 1.8, 0.3}], 
    None},

   {{{10^-4, 0}, {10^-3, Spacer@0}, {10^-2, 
      Superscript[10, -2]}, {10^-1, Spacer@0}, {10^0, 
      Superscript[10, 0]}, {10^1, ""}, {10^2, Superscript[10, 2]}}, 
    None}

   };

LogLogPlot[f1[i], {i, 10^-4, 100}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{10^-4.2, 130}, {10^3.35, 10^4.6}}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick, 27], FrameTicks -> ticks, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Purple, AbsoluteThickness@2.7], 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: The numbers on the x axis are 0, 0.01, 1, 100 in equal intervals. The segment you note is definitely not larger. Do you mean that the segment between 1 and 100 is longer? At any rate, I am in favour of equal intervals in axes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. No segment between 0 and 0.001 is longer. Since we can't take `Log[0]`, I placed 0 at 10^-4 and will cut the x-axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make ticks longer:

```
ticks2 = ticks /. {a_?NumericQ, b_} :> {a, b, {.02, 0}};
```

To create an inset that gives the desired look:

```
arrowhead = Graphics[{ EdgeForm[None], FaceForm[White], 
  Polygon[{{-1, -1}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, -1}}], Black, 
  CapForm["Butt"], AbsoluteThickness[2], 
  Line[{{{-1, -1}, {0, 1}}, {{0, -1}, {1, 1}}}]}];
inset[pos_: ImageScaled[{.2, .1}], size_: {1/2, 1/2}] := Inset[arrowhead, pos, 
  Automatic, size]
```

Use `LogLogPlot` with the options `Method -> {"FrameInFront" -> False}`, 
     `PlotRangeClipping -> False` and `Epilog -> inset[]`:

```
llplot = LogLogPlot[f1[i], {i, 10^-4, 100}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{10^-4.2, 130}, {10^3.35, 10^4.6}}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick, 27], FrameTicks -> ticks2,
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Purple, AbsoluteThickness@2.7], 
 ImageSize -> 600, Method -> {"FrameInFront" -> False}, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, Epilog -> inset[]]
```

[image]

You can also use `arrowheads` to "snip" part of the main plot:

```
llplot /. l_Line :> {Arrowheads[{{.015, .1, arrowhead /. Black -> Purple}}], Arrow @@ l}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use Graphics to create to symbol (//), and Overlay to superpose it to your plot.

```
   parallel = 
  Graphics[{Black, Thick, Line[{{0.300, 0}, {0.370, 0.1}}], 
    Line[{{0.350, 0}, {0.420, 0.1}}], White, AbsoluteThickness@6.1, 
    Line[{{0.325, 0}, {0.395, 0.1}}]}, ImageSize -> {30}, 
   ImageMargins -> {{105(*Control the horizontal position*), 
      0}, {23(*Control the vertical position*), 0}}];
Overlay[{LogLogPlot[f1[i], {i, 10^-4, 100}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {{10^-4.2, 130}, {10^3.35, 10^4.6}}, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick, 27], 
   FrameTicks -> ticks, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Purple, AbsoluteThickness@2.7], 
   ImageSize -> 600], parallel (*Here comes the symbol*)}, 
 Alignment -> {Left, Bottom} (*To control its initial position*)]
```

For the longer ticks, I suggest the CustomTicks package. http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5599/