# Cut out a region on x-axis

Tags: plotting

I have the following plot

```
Show[Plot[ Sinc[x - 4]^4, {x, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> Full], 
Plot[Sinc[x - 15]^4, {x, 10, 20}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
PlotRange -> Full], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

As you see there is a region where two functions are zero, i.e., between 6.5 and 12.6 approximately. I want to cut out a region in between, e.g. from 7 to 12 like the following:

[image]

How can I do this? I have seen some example but I couldn't figure out how this could be done.

Comment: See this. You need custom ticks. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/186110/23291

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci It doesn't really cut the region out, does it?

Comment: I get what you want to do, but I'd recommend that you don't do it. It really detracts from the readability of the plot.

Comment: @MarcoB What is your solution?

Comment: @Astrolabe My solution is to leave the plot as is. If the values on the horizontal axis mean something, then the peaks'  visual separation along that axis are also meaningful and should not be suppressed.

Comment: @MarcoB No, it doesn't detracts from the readability as you think. I really want to cut out the region and then glue both parts together, as I tried to show this in my post. OkkesDulgerci's solution is nice but it is just for the model problem. It doesn't work for the nonlinear functions or Listplot.

Answer (score 1):

With version 12.0 and later, use [`PlotGrid`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid/?i=PlotGrid&searchapi=https%3A%2F%2Fresources.wolframcloud.com%2FFunctionRepository%2Fsearch)

```
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][{{
   Plot[Sinc[x - 4]^4, {x, 0, 7},
    Frame -> True],
   Plot[Sinc[x - 15]^4, {x, 12, 20},
    PlotStyle -> Red,
    Frame -> True]}},
 ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Comment: Specify the `AspectRatio` to preference.

Comment: Interesting and easy solution! I'd use it for other purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186110/how-to-cut-some-part-x-axis) function.

```
arrowhead = 
      Graphics[{EdgeForm[None], FaceForm[White], 
        Polygon[{{-1, -1}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, -1}}], Black, 
        CapForm["Butt"], AbsoluteThickness[2], 
        Line[{{{-1, -1}, {0, 1}}, {{0, -1}, {1, 1}}}]}];
    inset[pos_ : ImageScaled[{.2, .1}], size_ : {1/2, 1/2}] := 
     Inset[arrowhead, pos, Automatic, size]

Show[Plot[Sinc[x - 4]^4, {x, 0, 15}, PlotRange -> Full, 
  Ticks -> {{{2, 2}, {4, 4}, {10, 15}, {15, 20}}, Automatic}, 
  Epilog -> inset[{7, 0}]], 
 Plot[Sinc[x - 10]^4, {x, 7, 15}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotRange -> Full], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Great! But, it is hard to adapt it to a Listplot or a nonlinear function, because one can't translate the graph by $x\mapsto x'$. It was a model problem to understand the cut out.